# How do I match BUY/SELL orders in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 4 column spreadsheet (Item Type, Order Type, Price, and Volume). The spreadsheet sort of operates like a trading book.

What I'm trying to do is create a formula for matching BUY and SELL order types from a list of orders by % volume.

So for example, if a BUY order for 100 Oranges at $12 exists and a SELL order for 100 Oranges at $13 exists, both would have a 0% match.

If a BUY order for 100 Apples at $12 exists and a SELL order for 85 Apples at $11 exists, the sell order match column would have 100% and the BUY order match column would have 85%.

I would then prioritize match by lowest price.

So for example:

```
Item Type        Order Type     Price     Volume     Match
----------       ----------    -------   --------   -------

Orange            SELL          $13        100       0%
Orange            BUY           $12        100       0%       
Apple             SELL          $11         85       100%
Apple             BUY           $12        100       85%
```

I've tried to string together endlessly complicated IF statements with different(VLOOKUPS, INDEX, MATCH) but are getting overly complicated and are starting to make no sense.

I don't even need someone to help with writing the formula, maybe just pointing me in the right direction structurally with what to use so I can write something that works.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There is no small formula to do that. What you may do is to use `SUMIFS` to get the volume of each order, then use `IF` to determine the value of match column. Another option is to write a custom VBA function to calculate that, on which case the complexity would be moved to VBA and you could have a simple formula on your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks GCSDC. 

I tried something sort of like that which was:

=IF(B3:B=B2,IF(C3:C<>C2,SUMIF(D3:D,<=D2)))

But wasn't able to get it to work. Not sure if that even makes sense :) But the idea was, if the item matches, and the order type doesn't match, sum the number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula (considering your data starts on cell A1):

```
=IF(SUMIFS($D$2:$D$5;$A$2:$A$5;A2;$B$2:$B$5;"SELL") = SUMIFS($D$2:$D$5;$A$2:$A$5;A2;$B$2:$B$5;"BUY"); 0; SUMIFS($D$2:$D$5;$A$2:$A$5;A2;$B$2:$B$5;IF(B2="SELL";"BUY";"SELL")))
```

which checks if the sum of the volume of buy and sell for an item type is equal. If it is, then take the sum  of the volume of the opposite operation. If not, return 0;

You could also use named ranges to make the formula cleaner and clearer.